# Loading on demand on multiple devices like mobile and ipad pro and ipad

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile, knockout.js

I want to scroll make working on the desktop, mobile and iPad and HD devices also. To stimulate the functionality what I have done is in a page I have a div tag called mainContent. I am using knockout to add some more text to the div tag.

Default Behaviour of the browser is that contents are over flowing the vertical scroll back appears. when the scroll bar is pulled down I write a function to add some more text in the div tag. I have put the same in codepen, but could not make it working, so I have put the same code below

Problem 1. Mobile devices, when I touch the mobile and slide down I am not able to get the function called up and I am not able to load more text in the div tag. even though scroll bar is visible, I don't see the result.

Problem 2. When the Browser size percent is set to 67% for HD resolution I don't get the scrollbar, Since I don't get the scroll bar I am not able to add more text elements.

Expectation. I am expecting to load the contents on demand. It can be through scroll bar which I am working on it. How ever if there is a better approach also please suggest.

```
 <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Test Page </title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome"> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.5.0/knockout-min.js"></script> 
</head>
<body>
    <div id="maincontent">
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy
        text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
        It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.
        It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages,
        and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    </div>

</body>
</html>

<script type="javascript">
function TestModal() {

    var self = this;

    self.fetchNext = function () {
        var result = $('#maincontent').val();
        var nresult = result + 'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industrys standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.     It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.       It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages,             and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.'
        $('#maincontent').val(nresult)
    }
    
}
 

$(document).ready(function () {

    var testModal = new TestModal();
    ko.applyBindings(testModal);


    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {
            testModal.fetchNext();
            alert('hdf');
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

https://codepen.io/jganesh/pen/jjYMbW

Answer (score 0):

**Problem 1**: based on your example in CodePen, to read/change the contents of a div you need to use the text() or html() methods, not val(). Currently your code doesn't even work on the desktop.

**Problem 2**: you should probably load enough content in #maincontent until you see the scrollbar... unfortunately it is difficult to determine the space occupied by the text in the device, because it depends on many factors (resolution, window size, formatting, etc.).

Comment: I have updated the sample.  it should be working on desktop.

Comment: Please.  if this could be possible or something which cannot be achieved

Comment: Your example in CodePen also requires jQuery and Knockout. You can do this with the Settings page.